# geth "Smartcard socket not found, disabling" warning message

Tags: go-ethereum

My node is running well in the last month. But somehow I restart the node and currently couldn't start probably, keep stuck at `smartcart socket not found`:

```bash
Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
```

My command:

```bash
geth --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=16384 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --allow-insecure-unlock
```

What may be the main reason of this warning message? How can I fix it?

Comment: That is not an error, just an information line. I don't think that will cause geth to fail. You can generate more log info adding `--verbosity 5` to the geth command.

Comment: @Ismael `--verbosity 5` did not bring much related to `stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory`; what may be this error related to?

Comment: @alper That line say geth was trying to connect with the smart card. Unless you have a smart card it is correct for that line to appear.

Answer (score 2):

remove `[Node.LogConfig]` section from ***config.toml***